# Is it possible to get the restaurant wait time estimate from google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I checked the API document from google map API. However, there's no directly answer about the API allow user to get restaurant wait time estimation.

[image]

Is there anyone has experience to download this information?

Comment: Which API document have you checked ?

Comment: It is not exposed by the Places API. There is a feature request for it (https://issuetracker.google.com/35827350) but it is there for two+ years now..

Comment: This is the API document I checked so far https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation

Comment: Did you get your answer? Is there any way to get wait time from google Map APIs

Answer (score 1):

Although such a feature is not yet exposed by the Places API, you can use [this `Python` library](https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes) to get what you need. Hope this helps